# Kill one thread in sleep mode in android

Tags: java, android

I have an android application, that have one thread, which will run after each 1 minute.
So my problem is, when i click one button, i have to reset the app, that means, it'll be
a fresh app.
So now when i clicked on that button, all the database and shared preference will clear.
But the thread will start again.

Now am using like this

```
if (killthread.isAlive()) {

           killthread.interrupt();                  


            }else {

              // Here what'll i do, I mean how to kill that thread, which in sleep mode.

}
```

Thank you
vishnu

Comment: i don't familiar with `android`, but in java you could use `join` when you want wait for another tread.

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry - yes you do.  But it is not clear that he *needs* to wait for the thread.

Answer (score 2):

> Thanks for the reply, Here when i click that button, that will come to the else part, but after 1 minute, the thread will start.So how to stop that in stage?

That will be something to do with the thread itself.  My bet is that you have coded it to ignore the interrupt.

---

OK, here's the code from your comment.

```
public void run() { 
    while (true) { 
        try { 
            Thread.sleep(60000); 
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { 
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
        }
    } 
}
```

What this does is to catch and silently ignore the exception that occurs when the thread is interrupted ... and just keep going.

If you want it to stop on an interrupt it should be this ... or something equivalent.

```
public void run() { 
    while (true) { 
        try { 
            Thread.sleep(60000); 
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { 
            return; 
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, can you specify more?

Comment: Can you show us the code where the thread is sleeping?  That will allow us to see what the problem really is (I think)

Comment: public void run() {
         
                while (true) {


                             try {
                          
                                Thread.sleep(60000);
                                
                           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                           }

}
 
}

Answer (score 1):

If a Thread is not alive it means

1) it's dead / finished. You cannot / dont need to do anything.

2) it is newly created / havent started yet. That is Thread.start() has not been called yet. In this case Thread.interrupt() will have no effect. The only thing you can do is some custom logic - notify the code that is going to start the thread that it's not needed anymore

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Here when i click that button, that will come to the else part, but after 1 minute, the thread will start.So how to stop that in stage?

Comment: The problem seems more complicated that I initially though. Nevertheless see my update, hope it hepls